# Perl and Data::Dumper::HTML + cgi

Tags: perl, data-dumper

First of all my english is not the best, thank you for understanding.

A portion of the code principal index.cgi

```
my ($url, $params) = split(/\?/, $ENV{'REQUEST_URI'}); 
my @pairs = split(/&/, $params);

foreach $pair (@pairs) {

    my ($name, $value) = split(/=/, $pair);
    $value =~ tr/+/ /;
    $value =~ s/%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;
    $PARAM{$name} = $value;
}
my $consulta = $PARAM{'buscar'};

print CGI::header();
print qq{<div style="font-family: monospace">\n};
$mysqltest->buscar($consulta);
print "\n<br /><br />\n";
print "\n</div>\n";
```

Module Search and result is print in cgi -> index.cgi

```
sub buscar{
    my $self = shift;
    my $keyword = shift;

    die "not work" if not $self->{mysqlopen};

    my $queryKeyword = $self->{connect}->prepare("SELECT * FROM savebookmarks WHERE MATCH (url,descripcion) AGAINST ('$keyword');");
    $queryKeyword->execute();

    while (my $resultKeyword = $queryKeyword->fetchrow_hashref()) {

        print dumper_html("$resultKeyword->{id} $resultKeyword->{descripcion} $resultKeyword->{url}");
    }
    $queryKeyword->finish();
    return;
}
```

Result print output in index.cgi

```
...
$VAR1 = 'The Python Standard Library â€” Python v2.7.2 documentation http://docs.python.org/library/';
$VAR1 = 'python-nmap : using nmap from python http://xael.org/norman/python/python-nmap/';
$VAR1 = 'Manejo de Excepciones en Python Â« Tutorial Python http://tutorial-python.com.ar/?p=193';
$VAR1 = 'FAQ\'s de Python - Foros del Web http://www.forosdelweb.com/f130/faqs-python-591053/#post2533652';
...
```

The problem that I have or I can not resolve is, the impression of the query adds '**$ VAR1 =' (it should not be)** affecting the result, some one to fix it?

---

this is perfect output i need. ->

```
...
'The Python Standard Library â€” Python v2.7.2 documentation http://docs.python.org/library/';
'python-nmap : using nmap from python http://xael.org/norman/python/python-nmap/';
'Manejo de Excepciones en Python Â« Tutorial Python http://tutorial-python.com.ar/?p=193';
'FAQ\'s de Python - Foros del Web http://www.forosdelweb.com/f130/faqs-python-591053/#post2533652';
 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
local $Data::Dumper::Indent = 0;
local $Data::Dumper::Terse  = 1;
```

in `buscar`, preferably right before the `dump_html` line. Note that Data::Dumper::HTML is a debugging tool.

Comment: local $Data::Dumper::Indent = 0;
    local $Data::Dumper::Terse  = 1;
    while (my $resultKeyword = $queryKeyword->fetchrow_hashref) {
        print dumper_html("$resultKeyword->{descripcion}\n$resultKeyword->{url}\n\n");
    }